# PHP: Code Interpretation Assistance

Tags: php

```
<?php
$headCount = 0;
while ($headCount < 3) {
    $flip = rand(0,1);
    if ($flip){
        $headCount ++;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
    }
    else {
        $headCount = 0;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">T</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Hi guys i understand the code except the part in line 5 `if ($flip){` why is it that there is no need to define the condition properly, such as `if($flip==1)`, and we can just write `if($flip)`?

Another question i have is the following:

```
//We will keep flipping a coin as long as the result is heads!
do {
    $flip = rand(0,1);
    if ($flip){
        echo $flip;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
    }
    else {
        echo $flip;
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">T</div>";
    }
} while ($flip);
```

i do not understand the last line "} while ($flip)", can someone explain it to me? i understand the whole statement as to implement the code until $flip is true. however, why does it stop the code from repeating when it shows "T"?

Thanks for the answer! was learning through codeacademy.com when i encounter this question.

Comment: This is because code checks only for non-falsy values like zero, empty string ans so on.

Comment: `0 = false` and `1 = true`

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 It does not check for plain boolean. It checks just for value other then `0` or `''`. $flip might have value '0', bet will still come out `false`.

Comment: Google before you ask question in the community, please.

Answer (score 3):

An if statement looks like: `if (expression)`.

The expression doesn't need to be a boolean, just something that can be converted to one.

The PHP manual has the rules for [converting to booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

In this case, you are generating integers. So if it is `0` then it is `FALSE`, otherwise it is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$flip = rand(0,1);` is going to give you either a **1** or **0** , So that value is going to be assigned to `$flip`.

Now you have this.. `if($flip)` here , 1 is considered as true and 0 as false. So depending upon the value of `$flip` , the `if` statement will be executed.

To make it clear... `if(1)` is **true** and `if(0)` is **false**

Answer (score 1):

Every value can implicitly be converted into a boolean `true` or `false` value. `$foo == true` is the same as `$foo` is the same as `$foo == true == true`. `$foo == true` coerces whatever value `$foo` is into something that is comparable to `true`, which is the same as just coercing `$foo` directly without needing to compare it to a boolean value. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for exhaustive comparison rule tables.

Comment: For the OP, in this context, "coerce" means to convert type. So we have a whole number, and changing it to a boolean requires PHP to follow certain rules: 1 = true, 0 = false. Strings have their own rules too (but don't apply here).

Answer (score 0):

From php.net: (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
>
> the integer 0 (zero) the float 0.0 (zero)
>
> the empty string, and the string "0"
>
> an array with zero elements
>
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
>
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).